# Is django server based on blocking code

Tags: django

I read somewhere that Django is a blocking code. Does that mean when I deploy my code, the server will be able to serve only one request at a time? Do I need to use some other framework like tornado to solve this purpose? Is Django only meant for development and debugging purpose? If it does not solve the purpose of deployment why not use node.js or some other framework.

Comment: What exactly then is your question?

Answer (score 3):

It means *each thread or process* can only serve one request at a time. But your server is normally configured to spin up multiple processes.